How do I bind Ctrl+Left in Python's tkinter
I have Entry box widgets in my Python application. I want to give it the pretty much default text-field behavior for the Ctrl+Left arrow, Ctrl+Right arrow, Ctrl+Backspace, and Ctrl+Delete buttons.
I have the following:
root.bind_class('Entry', "<Control-BackSpace>", my_func)
root.bind_class('Entry', "<Control-Delete>", my_func)
root.bind_class('Entry', "<Control-Left>", my_func)
root.bind_class('Entry', "<Control-Right>", my_func)

Everything works as expected with Backspace and Delete. However, tkinter has some default behavior for Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right (that Is not up to today's standards) which prevents this key combination from being bound. I also tried <Control-KeyPress> which works for any other Ctrl+Key combo except for the arrows because of the built-in behavior. I also tried first binding it to None or lambda e: None to unbind the built-in but that didn't work, even with bind_all.
I have a workaround solution that I don't like. It involves binding the widget to the Left and Right keys without Ctrl and then checking if the Ctrl modifier was used but that means executing this function on every Left/Right arrow press. Also, even if I did this, I'm not sure what would happen if the default binding is still in play. I would need to test and do further moves depending on what gets executed and when.
I would appreciate any ideas for getting rid of the default behavior and binding the <Control-Left> and <Control-Right> combos.

Please show the definition you're using for my_func. Are you returning the string "break"?

This is the function WITHOUT the logic for Ctrl-Arrow since I can't get it to work: link. It has no "break" string since it doesn't need it as the code can't even enter the function.
